# Powershell Resize-VHD is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Tags: powershell, vhd

I'm trying to use `Resize-VHD` cmdlet, but this results in the following error:

```
PS> Resize-VHD -Path "C:\Container.vhd" -SizeBytes 20GB
    Error:
        Resize-VHD : The term 'Resize-VHD' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
        At line:1 char:1
        + Resize-VHD -Path "C:\Container.vhd" -SizeBytes 20GB
        + ~~~~~~~~~~
            + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Resize-VHD:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
            + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

How do I fix that?

Comment: LoL! Another Masochistic Windowism! Not making basic Window functionality available, even though all other commands (via CMD) and GUI is available, but not the most basic powershell stuff like mounting your VHD!

Comment: to mount a vhd you can use diskpart.

Answer (score 48):

Turns out I needed to install Hyper-V features on Windows (even though I don't need Hyper-V itself, I use VHD as portable file container)

1. Go to `Control Panel | Programs and features | Turn windows features on or off`
2. Tick `Hyper-V | Hyper-V Management tools | Hyper-V Module for Windows PowerShell`
3. When installed, reboot if asked

Comment: Well, I had to install the `Hyper-V Platform | Hyper-V Services` part, too. (Which requires a reboot.) `Resize-VHD` finally started working only after that. Note: I was worried (as I've seen pranks like that from MS, and others...), but `Hyper-V Services` fortunately does not require a Hyper-V capable hardware.

Comment: Can we at least enable this from Powershell?

Comment: This doesn't work for Windows 8.1 as the `Hyper-V` features are not available. Is there a ways to install this by side loading?

Comment: This is incorrect, I do have Hyper-V on my Windows 8.1

Comment: In case anyone can't find Hyper-V like I couldn't, you can only have Hyper-V if you're on Windows 10 Enterprise, Pro, or Education ([source](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/quick-start/enable-hyper-v)).

Answer (score 38):

In case you have Windows 10 Home edition (so you have no Hyper-V at all), you can use alternative for Optimize-VHD cmdlet:

```
wsl --shutdown
diskpart
# open Diskpart in new window
select vdisk file="C:\WSL-Distros\…\ext4.vhdx"
attach vdisk readonly
compact vdisk
detach vdisk
exit
```

Thanks to @merkuriy for the [tip](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4699#issuecomment-627133168).

Comment: I do have Windows Enterprise, but for some reason, Windows refused to install the component of Hyper-V for PowerShell, so I used this method, and it totally worked.

Comment: wsl --shutdown, not commonly mentioned but fixes many issues