# Convert-VHD : The term 'Convert-VHD' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Tags: ubuntu, powershell, azure, vhd

I am getting the below error:

```
Convert-VHD : The term 'Convert-VHD' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet
```

in Azure Power shell installed on Ubuntu 18.04 (**Not on Windows**).

Command tried:
`Convert-VHD -Path src/vhdfile_old.vhd -DestinationPath tgt/vhdfile_new.vhd -VHDType Fixed`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Powershell Resize-VHD is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet](https://superuser.com/questions/1307441/powershell-resize-vhd-is-not-recognized-as-the-name-of-a-cmdlet)

Comment: @LotPings - Author is using Ubuntu not Windows.  However, it does appear, this is a caused by the fact the module itself requires Hyper-V

Comment: @LotPings The solution suggested works only on Windows. I am trying with Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

> with Azure PowerShell installed on Ubuntu 18.04.
>
> Command tried: Convert-VHD -Path src/vhdfile_old.vhd -DestinationPath tgt/vhdfile_new.vhd -VHDType Fixed

This particular command is a command is not supported by PowerShell Core at this time.

[Convert-VHD is a Hyper-V only cmdlet](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/hyper-v/convert-vhd?view=win10-ps) and actually requires Hyper-V to be installed on the system.

Convert-VHD isn’t listed as being in any of the Azure PowerShell modules.

Source: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/get-started-azureps?view=azps-1.7.0

Comment: Can I install `Hyper-V ` on Ubuntu?

Comment: No;  It’s a Windows only feature

Comment: So do we have any solution for Ubuntu (Any workarounds)?

Comment: @TomJMuthirenthi - I think my answer addresses that question