# How to shrink a VHDx file by the unallocated partition space that it contains

Tags: windows, partitioning, vhdx

I have a dynamic VHDX file/virtual hard drive that contains 3 partitions and 30GB of unallocated space.

How can I shrink the VHDX file/virtual hard drive by getting rid of that unallocated space inside it?

Apparently, it is possible with a Powershell command like so:

```
Resize-VHD -Path '\SomePath\My-VHD-File.vhdx' -ToMinimumSize
```

However, this doesn't seem to work on Windows 10 Professional, as it only seems to be available on Windows Server OSes.

Answer (score 2):

[Resize-VHD](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/hyper-v/resize-vhd?view=windowsserver2019-ps) is a Hyper-V tool cmdlet.

To install the Hyper-V cmdlets, run PowerShell as Administrator
and enter:

```
Install-WindowsFeature -Name RSAT-Hyper-V-Tools
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar as @sz, I had to [install the optional Windows 10 Hyper-V components](https://superuser.com/a/1307442/375374) (all of them, for some reason), and reboot.

Afterwards, the above Powershell command worked, and shrunk my VHDX file in about one second by 30GB.